# I'm trying to use PDFSharp but I can't find predefinedFont.csHelvetica

Tags: c#, sharppdf

This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using sharpPDF;

namespace Lightnings_Extractor
{
    class PDF
    {
        pdfDocument myDoc = new pdfDocument("Lightnings-Graphs", "Daniel");

        public PDF()
        {
            pdfPage myPage = myDoc.addPage();
            myPage.addText("Hello World!", 200, 450, predefinedFont.csHelvetica, 20);
            myDoc.createPDF(@"d:\mypdf.pdf");
            myPage = null;
            myDoc = null;
        }

    }
}
```

`predefinedFont` does not exist.

So I tried to write:

```
sharpPDF.Fonts.pdfAbstractFont font;
```

But then when I tried to create font, there is no `csHelvetica`

What am I missing here ?

Comment: You have missed that you are not using PDFsharp. You are using sharpPDF.

Comment: Right. Now i have downloaded the PDFSharp. But i can't find any dll. This is strange i have to compile now it on my own to build a dll file of the PDFSharp ?! I downloaded it from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfsharp/files/pdfsharp/PDFsharp%201.32/ the second file the 4.2mb file. And there is no any dll file/s.

Comment: Ok found it had to download the second file. Thnaks.

Answer (score 0):

I used sharpPDF in mistake. I have downloaded now PDFsharp.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following line by

```
      myPage.addText("Hello World!", 200, 450, predefinedFont.csHelvetica, 20);
```

by

```
      myPage.addText("Hello World!", 200, 450, myDoc.getFontReference(predefinedFont.csHelvetica), 20);
```

It works for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing `predefinedFont.csHelvetica` with `myDoc.getFontReference("Helvetica")`